# XPath expression, two Strings in one node

Tags: java, android, xpath, htmlcleaner

I downloaded html form, clean it with htmlCleaner.
Originally it looked like this (now it's well formed but I don't know simple way how to show it, I hope, this is sufficient):

```
...
<form action="complete" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Please fill in your username: 
<input type="text" name="employee" />
</BR>
Reason:
<BR/>
<textarea cols="50" rows="5" name="reason"></textarea>
</BR>
<input type="submit" value="Complete">
</form>....
```

**Is there XPath expression to extract "please fill in your username" and "reason" but in two separate strings?** 
Also, htmlCleaner doesn't support all expressions, here is the -> [list](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/doc/org/htmlcleaner/TagNode.html#evaluateXPath%28java.lang.String%29) <- of possible expressions.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "two separate strings" ?

Comment: I need xpath expression to extract **"Please fill in your username:"** and/or **"Reason:"**, but not **"Please fill in your username: Reason:"**, which I can do with `//form`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is just:

```
//input[@name="employee"]/@value
//input[@name="reason"]/@value
```

Or (if you need text in the `<form>` element):

```
//form/text()[1]
//form/text()[2]
```

Comment: But input tags are closed and doesn't contain my lines, those are in <form> tag.

Comment: In my example, `//form/text()[1]` works just like `//form` and extract **"Please fill in your username: Reason:"**.
`//form/text()[2]` doesn't work at all.
May be because cleaned xml looks different and what works on my example above doesn't in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because the two pieces of text you want to extract are both and ONLY children of FORM If they were each wrapped an a SPAN or DIV you could get to them separately.

You might be able to get them individually using 'child' and position